# как НЕ выполнять ajax запрос если respond пустой?

Tags: jquery, ajax

подскажите пожалуйста, как НЕ выполнять ajax запрос если respond пустой?

```
var startFrom = 2;
var count = 0;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if( $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() ){
        count++;
        $.ajax({            
            url: '/index.php/posts/index/products',
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {"startFrom" : startFrom, "count" : count, "categoryId": <?php echo $categoryId ?> },      
            success: function(response){
                //console.log(response);
                if (response!="") {
                    $('.products-grid').append(response);
                    startFrom++;
                }else{
                    $('.products-grid').append(response);

                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: если `respond` - имеется ввиду результат запроса ajax, то никак.

Comment: это код для ajax прокрутки товаров на сайте (если есть - добавляются), но дело в том, что когда выведены все товары, при скролле выполнятся аякс запрос, который ничего не возвращает, как переписать код, так чтобы когда товаров больше нету - запрос не выполнялся.

Comment: нужно перед запросом проверить что все уже выведены

Comment: @Grundy, по-подробней не подскажите пожалуйста?

Comment: что-то вроде: `if(не все выведены){$.ajax(...)}`

Comment: @Grundy скорее, `if (предыдущий ответ не был пуст) { $.ajax(...) }`

Answer (score 0):

Просто добавил флаг. inProgress = true, a когда response пустой флаг становится inProgress = false; И добавил проверку на inProgress в блок `if( $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() && inProgress)`